# Add value to hidden input field from an iframe for multiple iframes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am currently uploading files in an iframe and trying to get the name of the files to be passed to a hidden input field below the iframe on the parent page.

My current upload.php looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
if($("#fileName").val() != ""){
    var name = $("#fileName").val();
    $(this, window.parent.document).next('input').val(name);
}});
</script>
```

```
<body>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "xlsx"
&& $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "pdf") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, XLS, XLSX, DOC, DOCX & PDF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). '" id="fileName">';
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
</body>
```

My main issue is with trying to select the specific iframe that this is in, as it is used multiple times on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
if($("#fileName").val() != ""){
    var name = $("#fileName").val();
    **$(this, window.parent.document).next('input').val(name);**
}});
</script>
```